How to add text to a section in numerous-html-report-generator using Python
html-report-generator to generate HTML report.
I am trying to add some text into the section.
section.add_content({
    'figure': figure,
    'table': table,
    'text': 'How do I add some text in this section?'
})

Do we have any documentation for numerous-html-report-generator other than
https://pypi.org/project/numerous-html-report-generator/1.4.0/#description
Will greatly appreciate your help.
